# How to print all results of tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

How would I print the results of all tasks even those that did not run to completion?
For example, if I get an internal servor error or 404 not found error I still want to print all the results including the ones that did run to completion.

Here is my code:

```
public List<Task> tasksList = new List<Task>(); // List of tasks being created
public IList<WebsiteResult> WebResult = new List<WebsiteResult>(); // List that holds the web results

private void CheckNewResult()
{
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksList.ToArray(), CompleteTasks);
}

//Only runs if all tasks Ran to Completion
private void CompleteTasks(Task[] tasks){
    if(tasks.All(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
    {
        for(var numResults = 0; numResults < WebResult.Count; numResults++)
        {
            Print Results(numResults); //print each url result in the list
        }
    }
}


/// Method to send to request and get the response
public void PageCheck(Website webParam, int mySiteCounter)
{
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)
    // omit some code
    try 
    {
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        myReq.BeginGetResponse,
        myReq.EndGetResponse,
        null); 

        tasksList.Add(task);

        task.ContinueWith( t =>
        {
        // fill in web result list with the results using t.Result
        });
    }
    //catch omitted
}

public void PrintResults(int index){
// Print the results using info within web result list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue something within these lines... Notice the Task with generics. In my case I used string to represent maybe a message "Success!", to be used as the result. This can be any custom class from your library.

```
public List<Task<string>> tasksList = new List<Task<string>>(); // List of tasks being created
    public IList<WebsiteResult> WebResult = new List<WebsiteResult>(); // List that holds the web results

    private void CheckNewResult()
    {
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksList.ToArray(), CompleteTasks);
    }

    //Only runs if all tasks Ran to Completion
    private void CompleteTasks(Task<string>[] tasks)
    {
        tasks.Where(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).ForEach(x => {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Result);
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to convert a Task<Webresponse> list to a Task<string> list?

Comment: You can use any class you would like - I used string to show an example. No you cannot convert from WebResponse to string.

Comment: Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525460/taskwebresponse-wait-lasts-forever