# Handling a task status Faulted error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I am printing tasks results only when they run to completion. However, when a task's status is faulted it doesnt allow the others to become completed and printed out correctly. Is there a way to use ContinueWhenAny or any other method that will allow me to print even when a task is faulted?

Code:

```
public List<Task> tasksList = new List<Task>(); // List of tasks being created

private void CheckNewResult()
{
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksList.ToArray(), CompleteTasks);
}

//Only runs if all tasks Ran to Completion
private void CompleteTasks(Task[] tasks){
    if(tasks.All(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
    {
        for(var numResults = 0; numResults < WebResult.Count; numResults++)
        {
            Print Results(numResults); //print each url result in the list
        }
    }
}


public void PrintResults(int index){
// Print the results using info within web result list
}
```

Comment: you should see the TaskContinuationOptions of the TaskFactory class.

Comment: Msdn article on Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library),http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx ,last example might help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print all results of tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677104/how-to-print-all-results-of-tasks)